# ssl handshake with KMS server taking time(50sec) for a few requests event though socket connection timeout is 2000 as per logs

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-kms, ssl-handshake

We are using [AwsCrypto aws java sdk](https://aws.github.io/aws-encryption-sdk-java/com/amazonaws/encryptionsdk/AwsCrypto.html) for encryption and decryption. We follow the pattern mentioned in [this aws doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java.html) for using the same with data-key cache enabled.

For a few requests I am seeing intermittently TLS handshake with **kms** server is taking time(50 sec max before retrying to establish connection as per logs) but then there are other similar requests where TLS handshake is happening withing `ms`.

As per logs the socket connection timeout is set to `2000 ms` but for some reason the connection timeout is not occuring and thread is stuck on waiting for handshake response for more than 30 sec and ranging upto 50 seconds.

This is more problem as thread is blocked for no-reason and as our service scale it can be a bottleneck and we want to fix these latency spikes due to kms.

**Related logs**

```
*.*.awssdk.http.apache.internal.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory: Connecting socket to kms.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/52.119.199.83:443 with timeout 2000

2023-12-09T14:26:04.993Z *.*.awssdk.http.apache.*.conn.SdkTlsSocketFactory: Starting handshake

2023-12-09T14:26:35.029Z *.*.awssdk.request: Retryable error detected. Will retry in 43ms. Request attempt number 2
```

As can be seen the after handshake was initiated connection didn't break for 30 sec before retrying. But the timeout for connecting to socket was `2sec` as can be seen from 1st log

Is there some mis-configuration that's causing this or some other issue?

Our service is a ECS based service usign aws sdk 1.x

PS:
**For those voting to close kindly put a comment as to why this question should be closed. I would be happy to do that myself given that there is acceptable reason.**

Comment: The connect timeout will only control the TCP timeout of the SYN/SYNACK response, not the TLS handshake. I suggest you get a packet capture of the slow TLS handshake. Don't filter the capture. Look for a slow intermediate response between two of the TLS handshake steps. It might be that your client is doing a DNS lookup to confirm, e.g. hostname or validity of the server certificate. Look for slow DNS responses, etc.

Comment: (The close vote is for "lack of detail". I tend to agree with the voter - there's nowhere enough detail to be able to assist in a non-opinion-based way.)